# Having Cheese automatically take a pic and quit

Tags: camera

I use Cheese as my webcam software. I am trying to figure out a way to have it :

- Start
- Click a pic
- Exit

when a script is executed. The script should not be asking for permissions and there shouldn't be any interruptions. So far,

```
#!/bin/bash 
cheese
```

I could only get it to do step 1. How do I do steps 2 and 3?
The doc files don't mention an such option and I don't want to change the source code.
(I don't mind camorama either)

Comment: Have you seen [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516191/take-picture-using-webcam-from-command-line) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391456/take-picture-from-webcam-using-linux-command-line-bash)?

Comment: I hadn't. I believed this SE is the only one which would have relevant questions. Anyways, the mplayer solution doesn't work for me. It outputs a blank (green) png.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/253189/can-i-make-the-webcam-take-a-picture-when-an-incorrect-password-is-entered Follow the link and you might get the answer you want. In the first three steps.
after that you can write a crontab job.

Answer (score 1):

Voilá!  Steps 2 & 3 follow:

This works, although it's awfully timing critical, tweak as you see fit, tried to comment it decently so you can see what's going on.

You'll need to install **xdotool** for this to work, as we're simulating keypresses to take the picture and exit (package '*xdotool*')

Oh, and you'll need to turn off the '*countdown*' feature in preferences, otherwise it'll likely CTRL-Q (quit) out of the program before it actually takes the shot.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# L Nix <lornix@lornix.com>
# takeapic : take a photo with Cheese, using default settings, then exit
#
# start cheesing (2> because mine whines about cheesy stuff (ha!))
cheese 2>/dev/null &
# give WM some time to start up program (fails without this)
sleep 5
# set so we can determine if valid window(s) exist(s)
WINDOWIDS=""
# wait for up to 90 seconds (tweak this)
COUNTDOWN=90
while [ ${COUNTDOWN} -gt 0 ]; do
    WINDOWIDS=$(xdotool search --class "cheese" 2>/dev/null)
    if [ -n "${WINDOWIDS}" ]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
    COUNTDOWN=$(( ${COUNTDOWN} - 1 ))
done
# did we get anything?
if [ -z "${WINDOWIDS}" ]; then
    echo "Cheese never started, something's wrong"
    exit 1
fi
# the shutter button is ALT-T
for WIDS in ${WINDOWIDS}; do
    # if you combine these like xdotool allows, it fails
    xdotool windowfocus ${WIDS} 2>/dev/null
    xdotool key alt+t 2>/dev/null
done
# pause a moment while taking photo
sleep 1
# now CTRL-Q out of the application
for WIDS in ${WINDOWIDS}; do
    xdotool windowfocus ${WIDS} 2>/dev/null
    xdotool key ctrl+q 2>/dev/null
done
#
```